# Datasource paging and filtering - does entire dataset get fetched to build filter menu?

Tags: telerik-grid

Using the asp.net mvc grid, with paging (say 50) and filtering enabled. If the datasource will have thousands of records in it, does the entire (no page specified) dataset have to be fetched to determine what the filter menu items will be? I think I know the answer, but it makes sense that it would.  Is this the case?